# Make executable (.exe) from Python that includes MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, installation, executable, pyinstaller

I am making a Python program that uses a MySQL database. Now, I need a setup.exe file to set up the dependencies of the script and install it to windows computers.

Googling turned up PyInstaller, which mentions nothing about databases in its documentation.

To summarize, how could I make an .exe file that includes a MySQL database from a .py file?

Comment: Pyinstaller can only create python executables from python scripts. So any dependencies or external setup would have to be managed from a python script.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i was thinking too. But i thought that a simplier solution might exist, so i asked.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeSp, I am facing similar problem. How did you solve this ?